# Interpolation in data frame without making a new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

I have a pandas dataframe with an index and jut one column. Index has Dates. Column has Values. I would like to find the NewValue of a NewDate that is not in the index. To do that i suppose i may use interpolation function as: NewValue=InterpolationFunction(NewDate,Index,Column,method ext..). So what is the InterpolationFunction? It seems that most of interpolation functions are used for padding, finding the missing values ext. This is not what i want. I just want the NewValue. Not built a new Dataframe ext..

Thank you very very much for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Can you include a small example with input and expected output?

Comment: If I understood correctly you want the future values based on your existing value. That requires a forecasting technique in time series. There is no single method that does as such.

Comment: @BabakFiFoo. Thank you for your comment. I do not want future values. I just want a value that corresponds to a date that is not in my Dataframe.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny. Consider index: [1/1/2019, 1/1/2021]. Column: [ 5, 15]. NewDate (this is an input) == 1/1/2020. What is the NewValue?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you cannot find the missing values without constructing a base for your data. here is the answer to your question if you make a base dataframe:

You need to construct a panel in order to set up your data for proper interpolation. For instance, in the case of the date, let's say that you have yearly data and you want to add information for a missing year in between or generate data for quarterly intervals.

You need to construct a base for the time series i.e.:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start="1987-01-01",end="2021-01-01", freq="Q").values
panel = pd.DataFrame({'date_Q' :dates})
```

Now you can join your data to this structure and it will have dates without information as missing. Now you need to use a proper interpolation algorithm to fill the missing values. Pandas `.interpolate()` method has some basic interpolation methods such as polynomial and linear which you can find [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html).

However, much more ways of interpolation are offered by Scipy which you can find in the tutorials [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html).

Comment: Suppose that I have this date: "2011-02-01". How can i "join" this date to the "panel"?

Comment: The answer in the code is making a panel that has quarter interval. you can adjust the `freq` parameter accordingly to get your desired dates, in "2011-02-01" case, monthly. The panel will have all the dates within the given start and the end.  You can merge or join your df to this panel using appropriate method which you can find here:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Comment: I have the matrix with dates ready. The data is given. As I said a the begging i have a new date which is somewhere in between. The link has like 100 different examples and i am so confused right now. Could u please specify which function u would use so i may study it?

Comment: I personally used the answer that I gave you for my case where I had several missing variables in my data with unknown trend. My data was starting at 5 year interval until 2010 and yearly afterwards. I used linear interpolation as the moving average behaviour would eliminate any shocks I introduced to the interpolation. 
If your new data has additional date, I would suggest you to concat two data frames and then sort by data. Then you can use the interpolation method for missing data in between.